# How to extract Values of particular key in an object array without iterating over the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, array-map

Let's say I have an object array call **movies** like below.

```
movies = [{ id : 1,title : 'Black Panther'},{ id : 2,title : 'Avengers'},{ id : 1,title : 'Justice League'},{ id : 4,title : 'Infinity War'},{ id : 5,title : 'Spider man'}]
```

Is there anyway I can extract the value of particular key from every object ? Like this **titles** array.

```
titles = ['Black Panther','Avengers','Justice League','Infinity War','Spider Man']
```

At the moment I'm doing it using `map` function. Is there any other way to achieve this without iterating over every object. Can this be achieved using **ES6 rest/spread feature** ?

Comment: What is wrong with map? This is the exact use case for `map`!

Comment: I was just wondering if there is any other way . Thanks

Comment: even if spread was an option here (which is not) i think it is implemented with an iteration behind the scene.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot do this without looping through the array. And no, rest/spread wouldn't help.

You've said you're using `map`, which is probably the simplest way:

```
titles = movies.map(e => e.title);
```

```js
const movies = [{ id : 1,title : 'Black Panther'},{ id : 2,title : 'Avengers'},{ id : 1,title : 'Justice League'},{ id : 4,title : 'Infinity War'},{ id : 5,title : 'Spider man'}];
const titles = movies.map(e => e.title);
console.log(JSON.stringify(titles));
```

or with destructuring:

```
titles = movies.map(({title}) => title);
```

```js
const movies = [{ id : 1,title : 'Black Panther'},{ id : 2,title : 'Avengers'},{ id : 1,title : 'Justice League'},{ id : 4,title : 'Infinity War'},{ id : 5,title : 'Spider man'}];
const titles = movies.map(({title}) => title);
console.log(JSON.stringify(titles));
```

You could also use `for-of`:

```
titles = [];
for (const {title} of movies) {
    titles.push(title);
}
```

```js
const movies = [{ id : 1,title : 'Black Panther'},{ id : 2,title : 'Avengers'},{ id : 1,title : 'Justice League'},{ id : 4,title : 'Infinity War'},{ id : 5,title : 'Spider man'}];
const titles = [];
for (const {title} of movies) {
    titles.push(title);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(titles));
```

Comment: If so then the best way is to use `map` function rather than for loop right ?

Comment: @ThidasaParanavitharana: There are multiple definitions of "best." :-) I'd probably use `map` with an arrow function. It's clear, it's concise, and it's going to be optimized if necessary by the JavaScript engien.

Comment: I get it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, spread can't do that.
You could combine map with argument deconstruction:

```
list.map(({ title }) => title)
```

Or you could use `lodash/map`, which has a shorthand for your usecase:

```
import { map } from 'lodash'
map(list, 'title')
```

And with `lodash/fp`, you can even reuse your function elsewhere :D

```
import { map } from 'lodash/fp'
const getTitles = map('title')
getTitles(list)
```